# Javascript bug is stopping my XSS payload to execute

Tags: javascript, xss

The XSS vector is at the `*`, but the "com.test.admin.web.widgets.functionTest()" is not declared, hence my payload is not getting executed.

I can only change the script from the `*`

Following is the instance of the vulnerable code:

```
<select  name="sub_subissues" id="_subsubissues" onchange="com.test.admin.web.widgets.functionTest(*)" style="height:30px;">
```

As "com","test","admin","web","widgets" and "functionTest" are not defined in the page, the payload did not execute as the `onchange` attribute did not execute.
The characters `<>&"'` cannot be used as they are encoded.

so I tried:-

which resulted into:-

```
<select  name="sub_subissues" id="_subsubissues" onchange="com.test.admin.web.widgets.functionTest();var com = alert()" style="height:30px;">
```

But it is still asking for the rest that hasn't been defined, and I can't think of any other way to define them or ignore them.

How can i modify my payload to exploit XSS?

I expect this code to execute an alert(), with code changes from `*`:

```
<select  name="sub_subissues" id="_subsubissues" onchange="com.test.admin.web.widgets.functionTest(*)" style="height:30px;">
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It really isn't clear.

Comment: You can't use `*` as a function parameter. It's a language operator, not a possible variable name.

Comment: @Barmar
I know, what I mean is that the changes I can make to the code start from `*`, I can change the code only starting from `*`

Comment: @NoamI want to add an alert() with code additions to the `*` instance

Answer (score 0):

Put the call to `alert()` in the argument. Function arguments are evaluated before trying to call the function, so the alert will execute even if the function doesn't exist.

```
onchange="com.test.admin.web.widgets.functionTest(alert())"
```

Comment: For me this does not solve, as I said earlier I can only add a script from `*`

Comment: Then I don't think you can do it. You can't continue after an error.

Comment: my goal was to try to set what is not set so that the alert works

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "set what is not set". Please post actual code, and explain clearly how you're modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

JS is imperative language, so it by design should not allow code written after, modify behaviour of code written before.
[`Member Access`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) have the same precedence as `Function Call` (the greatest after `(` and `)`), so if you can't inject something before first `.` or create valid `com` object you are out of luck with injecting expression.

---

So you can try luck with statements:

`var` and `function` are hoisted, but this will only declare something (not define). and only for 1 level deep.

`label:`:label names can't contain dot.

Seems like nothing can help you.